# Schema slicing/slimming tools

Tags: xml, xsd

I have 20,000 lines+ ACORD (a standard schema for insurance industry) schema. I want to "slim" or "slice" the schema to include only those data elements that we will be using in our transaction. Although I can certainly do this manually, it is a painstaking process.

Has any one used utilities to facilitate the definition of these sub-schemas? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) is a tool that can do this very easily.

Conceptually, it involves two modules of work:

- Organizing source XSDs in a schema collection.
- Defining a "Release" with one or more XSD file sets.

Both interactive (using the graphical user interface) and command line are supported, the latter for use with continuous integration stacks and such.

Let's assume that what you want is to release only UserAuthRequest/Response and all other dependencies. An example setup is shown below; the main elements are:

- The collection (here v2.26.0)
- A release (ACORD Release) referencing this particular version. The idea is if in the future you add another version, you can "upgrade" your release to reference the new version instead, thus easily maintaining adherence to a newer version of the standards without redoing the "edits".
- A file set (20% Release) with associated filters. In this case I've setup a single file, which is "seeded" with two elements UserAuthRequest and UserAuthResponse.

[image: QTAssistant ACORD setup]

You then have the ability to further customize the content model through injection of sequences, exclusions, renaming, retyping, XML namespace "retargeting" etc. - things we call "refactoring". Click on References, then expand Local Exclusions if there's a particle you want to get rid of, etc. Once you're finished, click **Generate** - and you're done.

[image: QTAssistant filtered ACORD release]

The saved XSR file could then be passed as a parameter to a command line utility to generate the same from a label, and have the generated file(s) checked back in, passed to xsd.exe or xjc

As you can see from the stats, from 4633 elements, 1123 complex types and 589 simple types, you're left with 40 elements, 14 complex types and 6 simple types.

You can add/adjust as you wish what you want in the output files, by choosing the particular component you want; the refactoring engine will automatically pull in all depedendencies.

By default, the generated file is sorted: simple types, complex types, elements. You can override it and maintain a "original" layout by pointing to a "model file" - could be the original XSD, or any other one. This come in handy when people want to rely on "dumb" text/xml comparison tools for whatever compliance reason.

[image]

Bonus things include views showing the relationships between XSD components...

[image]

or, where "inferrable", the relational view (on .NET is called a DataSet) of the XSD:

[image]

Comment: Petru ... Great Explanation. QTAssist seems to do exactly what I am looking for. Will try it out and most likely will come up with more questions. Thank You !